# Jquery UI Tabs only reload the tab contents

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, user-interface, tabs

```
<div id="example">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="ahah_1.aspx"><span>Content 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="ahah_2.aspx"><span>Content 2</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="ahah_3.aspx"><span>Content 3</span></a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I am using Jquery ui tabs in Ajax mode. When my page ahaha_1.aspx postbacks my main page dissapears and I am redirected to ahaha_1.aspx. How do I get it to only reload the tab and not the entire page.

Comment: jQuery code would really help :)

Comment: How can you be using jQuery tabs and have no code? I'm confused...

Comment: I just have this line $("#tabs").tabs();

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#example').tabs({
    load: function(event, ui) {
        $('a', ui.panel).click(function() {
            $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

from [JQuery ui - Tabs Demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

Answer (score 0):

To reload the tab you would need a button or something to trigger this command which would then reload the currently selected tab.

```
$("#tabs").tabs('load', $("#tabs").tabs("option","selected"));
```

$("#tabs").tabs("option","selected") is grabbing the currently selected tab.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this

```
 $('#tabs').tabs({ active: $('#<%= hdf_tabNumber.ClientID %>').val() });
      $('#tabs').tabs({
           activate: function(event, ui) {
               var selected = $(this).tabs('option', 'active');
               $('#<%= hdf_tabNumber.ClientID %>').val(selected);
                //alert($('#<%= hdf_tabNumber.ClientID %>').val());
           }
 });
```

Create this input tag

```
<asp:HiddenField  id="hdf_tabNumber" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
```

at your body code.